# How do I make a css/js object same on all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

On Firefox my object looks just fine, but on Chrome/IE it has ghosting. You can see it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DFCB3/3/

How it looks on other browsers:
http://gyazo.com/0ee27df5904ff3aca036191f69e89cb6.png

I think this code might have something to do with it:

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Bitcoin.png" class="grayscale"/>
```

How do I make it so it works on all browsers like on Firefox?

Comment: It copied your code and test it on firefox and chrome, and there wasn't any problem...
what's the problem?

Comment: "ghosting"? what's "ghosting"? remove the 'class="grayscale"' part and see if that changes something

Comment: Why don't you try to get the image you want from the beginning into one image and then do the morphing with the transitions?

Comment: Also, add jQuery to your fiddle if you want the script to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, you need to add jQuery to your Fiddle.

Second, you need to change the following css:

```
img.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter ….3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

To this:

```
img.grayscale {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter ….3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or otherwise just make both img tags `position: absolute;`

http://jsfiddle.net/FdD5L/